# DotNetNuke (Documents Module)

Tags: dotnetnuke

I added a documents module to a page and when i add new documents it brings back an error = 
Error: Documents is currently unavailable.
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at DotNetNuke.Modules.Documents.Document.LoadPagingSettings() at DotNetNuke.Modules.Documents.Document.BindData() at DotNetNuke.Modules.Documents.Document.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Can anyone help please!

Comment: Same here - just built a new DNN 05.06.02 (the current) site and tried adding the 04.01.01 documents module and same error. Just about to try the last version.

Answer (score 0):

can only suggest to check your log in admin -->> Event Viewer to see if there is any more detailed information on the Error.